# Implementing ICollection in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am new to Angular. Can you please guide me how can I implement the Angular Reactive Form that can produce the following json result?

```
{  
"firstName":"",   
"middleName":"",   
"lastName":"",
   "addressBook":[{
     "addressLine1":"",
     "addressLine2":"",
     "addressLine3":""
  },
 "addressBook":[{
     "addressLine1":"",
     "addressLine2":"",
     "addressLine3":""
  }]
}
```

Following is the form structure I have:

```
this.userForm= this.fb.group({
        firstName: [],
        middleName: [],
        lastName: [],
        emailAddress: [],
        password: [],
        addressBook: this.fb.group({
            addressLine1: [],
            addressLine2: [],
            addressLine3: []
        })
    });
```

I am really stuck here. Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: your json has errors.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use `getRawValue`: `this.userForm.getRawValue();` that will result in a javascript object.
2. If you put that object in `JSON.stringify(formObject);` you will get your `json`.

**[getRawValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue)**

> Retrieves all values regardless of disabled status. The value property is the best way to get the value of the group, because it excludes disabled controls in the FormGroup.